# No yellow highlight for the xpath in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, xpath, element, highlight

I'm having issue with no yellow highlight for element locator using xpath. Please help. Thanks

[Unable to get yellow the hightlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gz4M.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I just check on the chrome and it's as expected.

[image]

Comment: I did not use ctrl+F for the 'Find by string,selector, or XPath' box to open up  but, used the 'Filter' box

Comment: what you are using is `style` filter and that will search with in styles not the matching elements using css/xpath. Please use `Find` and enter your css/xpath in `Find by string,selector, or XPath`.